# How to optimize a query which has inner SELECTs in HAVING clause

Tags: mysql

I have a query which selects top3 basketball players by their average points, scored during their games. Basketball player can be included in this top3 list if he played more than 50% games of his team:

```
SELECT games_stats.player, AVG(games_stats.points) AS points_avg
FROM games_stats
WHERE EXISTS (
SELECT *
FROM players
WHERE games_stats.player = players.id AND status = 'active') AND season = 28293
GROUP BY games_stats.player
HAVING COUNT(games_stats.game) >= ((
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM games
WHERE home IN (
SELECT team
FROM teams_players
WHERE season='28293' AND player=games_stats.player) AND season='28293' AND (STATUS='finished' OR STATUS='complete')) + (
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM games
WHERE away IN (
SELECT team
FROM teams_players
WHERE season='28293' AND player=games_stats.player) AND season='28293' AND (STATUS='finished' OR STATUS='complete'))) / 2
ORDER BY points_avg DESC
LIMIT 3
```

The problem is that this query is very expensive in server resources and runtime: it takes to execute even 0.54 seconds, and server of my basketball website often gets overloaded due to that, it even crashes sometimes. Caching query results is not enough and helps just a little bit, because basketball games are played and stats are updated almost daily.

I had one idea in mind, hoping it will reduce execution time: I tried to reduce this repeated sub-query:

```
SELECT team
FROM teams_players
WHERE season='28293' AND player=games_stats.player
```

That means I wanted to turn my query into something like that:

```
SELECT games_stats.player, AVG(games_stats.points) AS points_avg, CONCAT(SELECT team FROM teams_players WHERE season=28293 AND teams_players.player=games_stats.player) AS ids_of_teams
FROM games_stats
WHERE EXISTS (
SELECT *
FROM players
WHERE games_stats.player = players.id AND status = 'active') AND season = 28293
GROUP BY games_stats.player
HAVING COUNT(games_stats.game) >= ((
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM games
WHERE home IN ids_of_teams AND season='28293' AND (STATUS='finished' OR STATUS='complete')) + (
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM games
WHERE away IN ids_of_teams AND season='28293' AND (STATUS='finished' OR STATUS='complete'))) / 2
ORDER BY points_avg DESC
LIMIT 3
```

Unfortunatelly, CONCAT() returns a string of concatenated IDs of teams (I need an array). So, **THE MAIN QUESTION**: how can I reduce/optimize this repeated sub-query? How to set a "field" which "stores" an array of IDs, got in repeated sub-query?

**EDIT**: now I see that my question was wrong - it seems the problem was in different place. I have a question if I could optimize HAVING clause which has inner SELECT queries.

By the way, do you have other ideas how to write more efficient queries about best players and their stats? Just note that I have to "select these top 3 players who played more than 50% games of their teams".

---

[image: Database structure]

Explanation of database structure:
Table "players" stores data about each player in basketball league. Player can change the team in the next season, or during the current season, so the pivot table "teams_players" describes what teams did player present during his career;

Pivot table "teams_players" has foreign keys "team", "player" and "season", referencing IDs of tables "teams", "players" and "seasons".

Table "games" stores data about games; fields "home" and "away" store IDs of opposing teams in the game;

Table "games_stats" stores statistical data of each player by game. It has foreign key "game", referencing games.id. It also has foreign key "player", referencing players.id.

**EDIT**: output of EXPLAIN:

[image: Query Explain output]

Comment: " I try to reduce this repeated sub-query" ..... You do not have to do that because MySQL optimizer should do that for you!   Show [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/using-explain.html) output for this query

Comment: And, please, add the exact MySQL version that you are using.

Comment: My MySQL version on my local machine: Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.24, for Win64 (x86_64),
On Live server: Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.52-38.3

Comment: @Luuk , thank you for advice about EXPLAIN command... Now I see that the title of my question is totally inappropriate. I will study more what command Explain shows, and I still wait for your advices :) I have added an output of EXPLAIN command

Comment: @Nae  , not, I do not have to use a single statement. Please provide your solution, if you have alternative vision of this question.

Comment: @Nae , values 'finished' and 'completed' are from games table, status field. The game can be just 'finished' but not imported from API, 'completed' is fully completed and all stats are imported from API of sports events.

Comment: What if a player played half of one teams' games, and half of the other?

Comment: @Nae , it's a good question, but very rare corner-case. A widget of "Best players" shows a player with a logo of his current team, then. This query is generated by Laravel query builder (I know how to construct queries in that framework). After executing this query and getting a collection of results (objects), names of players and team logos are got by additional methods, but surprisingly, it does not cause serious "n+1 problem". It seems only this newly written query causes such performance issues (0.54 seconds).

Comment: @Is there table for teams?

Comment: @Nae , yes, it is. It is simply absent in this query, and I decided not to show it in my attached images because database diagram is very large due to large amount of fields in each table.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  The speedup may be as simple as adding a composite index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think with the help of temporary tables it should be simpler and more efficient. Hard to tell with an actual fiddle:

```
SET @var_season := 28293;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_team_games_played;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_team_games_played
    (PRIMARY KEY (id))
SELECT t.id, COUNT(0) AS Count
FROM games g
JOIN teams t ON t.id IN (g.home, g.away)
WHERE TRUE
    AND g.season = @var_season AND (g.STATUS IN ('finished', 'complete'))
GROUP BY t.id
;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_player_team_points;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_player_team_points
    (PRIMARY KEY (player, team))
SELECT gs.player, gs.team, SUM(gs.points) AS points_in_team_games
FROM games_stats gs
JOIN players p ON gs.player = p.id AND p.status = 'active' -- reorder based on index
WHERE TRUE
    AND gs.season = @var_season
GROUP BY gs.player, gs.team
;

SELECT tptp.player, AVG(tptp.points_in_team_games) AS points_avg
FROM tmp_player_team_points tptp
JOIN tmp_team_games_played tgp ON tptp.team = tgp.id
GROUP BY tptp.player
-- I took the liberty to make a player play more than a half
-- as opposed to greater than or eqaul to half
HAVING COUNT(0) > (MIN(tgp.Count) * 2)
ORDER BY points_avg DESC
LIMIT 3
;
```

Comment: thank you for your attention and efforts. I checked your solution with simply copy/paste into MySQL query window - of course it did not work :D No errors, but 0 results. I will analyse it tomorrow and study about MySQL variables and temporary tables a little bit, because I lack this knowledge. Now I give you big thanks and I vote up your answer for your attention, for your efforts and expertise :)

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I have been asked to return to this problem recently, and your solution was the nearest solution I made. I just created a TABLE, instead of TEMPORARY TABLE of best players, and cron job updates records of best players one time per day. Cron job uses this complex and slow query I showed above. So, all in all, your solution is the best, and basketball website works just perfect now! Caching is no longer needed - now "cache" is that table of best players :) Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

The (too complex) HAVING clause makes me think that this query could be written otherwise.

Can you check this, and comment on the results?:

```
SELECT 
  games_stats.player, 
  AVG(games_stats.points) AS points_avg
FROM games_stats
INNER JOIN (
  select team
  from games
  inner join teams_players on (teams_players.team=home OR teams_players.team=away)
                           and teams_players.season=games.season
  where games.season=28293
    and (games.status='finished' or games.status='complete')
  ) x on x.team=games_stats.team
WHERE 
  season=28293
  and EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM players
    WHERE games_stats.player = players.id AND status = 'active') 
GROUP BY games_stats.player
ORDER BY points_avg DESC
LIMIT 3;
```

Comment: Thank you for your efforts to help me. I corrected a little bit your answer - fixed names of database tables and their fields. Unfortunatelly, your query takes to execute 40 times longer (up to 20 seconds) - that's even much worse. I even terminated the execution of query in my SQL app.

Comment: That's not good, but it is hard to write a query without knowing the data....  Myabe you can create a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7)?